# Wordcount execution on the Hadoop Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop

I follow a tutorial to learn Hadoop with Java. I write the `Wordcount` program in the `IntelliJ` and the job was successful and I can see the proper output file. Now, I would like to run the app in the Hadoop cluster and that fails. The Hadoop setup is itself fine and starts properly. Here is what I have in the directory,

```
$ hadoop fs -ls 

2018-08-18 09:15:44,012 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - chaklader supergroup          0 2018-08-17 12:17 Wordcount
-rw-r--r--   1 chaklader supergroup     530989 2018-08-15 13:13 forum_users.tsv
```

The `pom.xml` file in the app is provided below,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>wordcount</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>wordcount</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Hadoop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.test.hadoop.WordCount</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the project setup,

[image]

When I run the program, it creates a `JAR` file namely `wordcount.jar` and I put that inside the `Downloads` directory. Finally, I execute the command to run the job in the `Hadoop` cluster,

```
$ hadoop jar  Downloads/wordcount.jar  /Users/chaklader/IdeaProjects/Wordcount/src/main/java/com/test/hadoop/WordCount  /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Input/input.txt  /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Output

Usage: WordCount needs two arguments <input> <output> files
```

The error informs that the `WordCount needs two arguments <input> <output> files`. I checked all the paths and seems correct.

What is the issue here?

Comment: tutorial link: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-hadoop/apache-hadoop-wordcount-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the package path of WordCount class. 
Change this

```
$ hadoop jar  Downloads/wordcount.jar  /Users/chaklader/IdeaProjects/Wordcount/src/main/java/com/test/hadoop/WordCount  /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Input/input.txt  /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Output
```

to

```
$ hadoop jar  Downloads/wordcount.jar  com.test.hadoop.WordCount /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Input/input.txt /user/chaklader/Wordcount/Output
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I have tried with several changes

Comment: @userX Then there must be some other issue with your changes. Above syntax is the right way to execute a hadoop job.Please remove the downcast voting

Comment: I havent provide the downvote, but, I see your point. I find it helpful though

Answer (score 0):

The command in the tutorial was not correct. It should be

```
$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar Wordcount/Input/input.txt  Wordcount/Output
```

After we created the `JAR` file, it's not required to provide the Java classes path that creates it in the first place.